# Why can't we access outer scope variables from a class' inner class?

Tags: python

When declaring an class' inner class in python, we can't access variables from the outer scope :

```py
class A(object):
  a = 42
  class B(object):
    b = a
```

```
<ipython-input-2-6f9865d75654> in <module>
----> 1 class A(object):
      2   a = 42
      3   class B(object):
      4     b = a
      5 

<ipython-input-2-6f9865d75654> in A()
      1 class A(object):
      2   a = 42
----> 3   class B(object):
      4     b = a
      5 

<ipython-input-2-6f9865d75654> in B()
      2   a = 42
      3   class B(object):
----> 4     b = a
      5
```

...While intuitively, `a` should be a non-local variable, accessible (intuitively it should, but I know it's not like this). By the way, in this exact situation, it is actually impossible to refer to a without doin some hacks... (Since che class A does not already exist, and only its body is executed).

However, with function, it is possible :

```py
def A():
  a = 42
  class B(object):
    b = a
```

Thus, I was wondering why in the class one, it is not possible, and why has it been implemented this way ? (what prevents the to bind like a function `nonlocal` variable ?)

Comment: is `a` actually a class attribute?

Comment: This shows an example of accessing a class attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9760696/2359945

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39537508/3001761.

Comment: It will eventually, but at this state of the interpretation, one could expect `a` to be just a variable in an outer scope. This scope would the the result to `locals()` called in the class body. (this is my intuition if I had designed python and thus, I am wondering why it has not been done this way)

Comment: @RazzleShazl : This is not about how to access it, but Why is it implemented like this ?
There are plenty of solution, and some are elegant, but my question on this post is "Why is it a problem in the first place" ?

Comment: Note : when executing with `exec(compile('class C: b=a', ...), {}, {'a':42})` There is the same problem (that is not with `exec(compile('class C: b=a', ...), {'a':42}, {})`)